# Mantener teclado oculto en EditText Android

Tags: java, android

Tengo un campo el cual lee un código de barras mediante un lector, el lector al momento de pistolear el código escribe el contenido y envía un enter.

Mi idea es que el campo en donde se escribe el contenido del código de barras no muestre el teclado virtual al momento de seleccionarlo ya que no es necesario que la persona escriba o edite los dígitos en dicho campo.

en esto momento mantengo el siguiente código, el cual "bloquea" el edittext y no se muestra el teclado virtual, pero a la vez quita la linea de escritura, entonces no se nota muy bien si el campo esta seleccionado o no.

```
txtBarcode.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b){
                    txtBarcode.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

                }
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen no se aclara bien si el campo esta seleccionado o no .
¿Existe alguna forma de que quede marcado de mejor manera el campo? y que realice la misma acción que efectúa ahora.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDIT:**
La idea es que al momento de apretar el campo, no se visualice el teclado. En el gif el codigo es el siguiente:

```
txtBarcode.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b){
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);


                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el metodo setShowSoftInputOnFocus(), colocando valores true/false entre los parentesis , controlaras si el teclado se abre o no cuando tenga el foco, por ejemplo

```
objecto.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

con esto se cierra el teclado cuando  el objecto   recibe el foco.

pero una cosa, tu codigo tiene dos fallos:

El **setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)** que estas utilizando, es para controlar el tipo de teclado que se mostrara, es decir si sera un teclado númerico, o un teclado con caracteres y numeros, por eso no te funciona.

Ademas otro fallo es que en el onfocusonchange , no debes controlar si el edittext recibe el foco o no con un condicional , simplemente colocando el metodo que te indico  en el evento onfocuschange ya funciona, ejemplo:

```
  txtBarcode.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                ((EditText)view).setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he intentado con eso y me aparece un error en el getWindow()

Comment: Se sigue abriendo el teclado al momento de presionar el EditText :c

Comment: Edite la pregunta para mostrar como esta funcionando en este momento con el codigo de su respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu paciencia ajaja, efectivamente, no se muestra el teclado al momento de presionarlo. Pero si ya estaba abierto por otro campo, no se cierra al presionarlo.

Comment: La verdad es que da muchos problemas en el onfocuschange, es posible que entre en conflicto con algun codigo interno del Edittext,esto sucede porque se queda abierto en el otro EditText ,a mi se me han acabado los codigos que utilizo para estos casos, si ves que no lo consigues, prueba con diseño alternativo , por ejemplo que  el edittext no se pueda escribir, y cuando el usuario  presione un boton de "modificar dato", permita al usuario escribir/modificar el contenido

Answer (score 0):

Si no es necesario que la persona teclee algo, en algún momento. Te recomiendo que cambies el componente y en lugar de utilizar un EditText, usa un TextView, el cual cambiarás cuando el código sea escaneado. Con esto evitarás totalmente tener el teclado virtual.

Comment: Si usa un TextView no podrá ingresar valores. Recuerda revisar [answer], esta publicación es como comentario, trata de obtener reputación para poder comentar, saludos.

Comment: el lector lo que hace es escribir sobre un campo de texto :/. no tengo forma de obtenerlo si no es con un EditText. Con Zxzing por ejemplo, se puede realizar lo que tu planteas pero se utiliza la cámara del teléfono como lector y un botón para escanear, entonces cuando lee algo le envía el campo al textview. Pero no es el caso.